# How design pattern is this?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I need help. I am searching on the internet how to call design pattern for my code but I haven't found it.
I have a class (f.e. exercise) with getter and setter and manager which have all exercise (in the DB or array, doesn't matter). In my application, I have the one instance of exercise manager and I work with exercises through it.

Exercise :

```
public class Exercise {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Exercise manager:

```
public interface ExerciseManager{
    void createExercise(Exercise exercise);

    Exercise getExerciseById(Long id);

    Collection<Exercise> getAllExercises();

    Exercise getExerciseByName(String name);

    void updateExercise(Exercise exercise);

    void deleteExercise(Long id);

    Boolean isIdInDB(Long id);
}

public class ExerciseManagerImpl implements ExerciseManager{
    ...
}
```

Main (f.e.):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataSource dataSource = <some datasource>;
    ExerciseManager exerciseManager = new ExerciseManagerImpl(dataSource);
    Exercise newExercise = new Exercise();
    newExercise.setName("Name1");
    exerciseManager.createExercise(newExercise);
    Exercise existExercise = exerciseManager.getExerciseByName("Name1");
    exerciseManager.deleteExercise(existExercise.getId());
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this is a named design pattern in the first place?

Comment: Also, another unrelated question, why does `getExerciseById` return a `Dragon` rather than an `Exercise`?

Comment: I don't know, I saw similar structure in the more codes so I think that exist any design pattern for describing this structure.
Sorry, I forgot to change a name of a class, of course, Exercise is correct. (I have already edited my post.)

Comment: This to me looks simply like a sensible interface design.

Comment: Looks like typical implementation using JPA - only there is no @. It is code that represents a model - and some methods that interact with your model. Just because you have something called a 'Manager' doesn't mean you have suddenly a design pattern. I don't see the point of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a *[data access object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)*, which would be part of your *persistence layer*; it serves as an interface between application code (which uses `Exercise` instances) and a persistence mechanism (such as an `EXERCISES` database table), decoupling the former from the latter.

Answer (score -1):

There are some which are involved:

- Factory: only one class is allowed to create a certain type of object.
- Singleton: only one instance exists of a type.
- Mediator: dedicated to operate and manage a certain type.

But I think, what you're looking for is **ORM**, let's see what Wikipedia says:

> Object-relational mapping (ORM, O/RM, and O/R mapping tool) in
>   computer science is a programming technique for converting data
>   between incompatible type systems in object-oriented programming
>   languages. This creates, in effect, a "virtual object database" that
>   can be used from within the programming language.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping